# LWC reopen the same tab with workspace API

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, workspaceapi

Hi I need some assistance for one of the scenario, i am trying to open a LWC from another LWC in which target LWC is Wrapped inside the aura component. the problem is that whenever user clicks new tab gets opened, is there any way if the tab is already open the user should navigate to the same tab.
below is my code :

```
clickOnNext(evt) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c_ABCComponent'
            },
            state: {
                c__ITC: this.ITCRe,
            }
        });
    }
    
<aura:component implements='flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable access:global'>
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id='WAPI'/>
    <aura:handler name='init' value='{!this}' action='{!c.init}'/>
      <c:AsdComponent3 />
</aura:component>

({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        let workspaceAPI = component.find('WAPI');
        workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then((response) => {
            let idOfOpne= response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: idOfOpne,
                label: 'Loading This Tab'
            });
            
        })
        
)}
```

Comment: is there is no solution for this issue??

Comment: @sfdcfox kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a limitation in the Target behavior in Lightning Console. All target behavior opens a new workspace tab and there isn't an option to open in the same workspace tab. I think this would be good to submit an idea to Salesforce if there isn't one already.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_smart_link_targets.htm&language=en_US&type=5